# How do I stop the slave from running the code until master sends a new value? I2C

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, i2c

I'm a total noob when it comes to Arduino. I'm slowly learning stuff. I was trying this code which basically gets input in Arduino1(master) and displays the character in serial monitor of Arduino2(slave). The code words just find but I just need the slave to wait until the master sends the next character. Right now, the slave is continuously printing the character.

Master code:

```
    #include "Wire.h"
    char ch;

    void setup() {

      Serial.begin(9600);
      Wire.begin();

    }

     void loop() {
      while(Serial.available()==0)
      {}
      ch=Serial.read();
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print("The character that you entered is ");
      Serial.println(ch);

      Wire.beginTransmission(9);
      Wire.write(ch);
      Wire.endTransmission();

        }
```

Slave code:

```
#include "Wire.h"
char x;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin(9);
  Wire.onReceive(Event);

}
void Event(char bytes){
  x = Wire.read();
}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("The character that you entered in the other Arduino is ");
  Serial.println(x);
}
```

I know that this will be simple but I just can't quite figure out what to do. Please help me out

Comment: Changed the code. Please check now

Comment: send more bytes, read more bytes. collect bytes into a buffer, send the whole buffer and receive a buffer

Comment: @Juraj Please translate this into noob language. Sorry. Is there any modification to the code that I can do so I can get the slave to do this?

Comment: see master_writer and slave_reader examples in IDE File menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include "Wire.h"
volatile char x;
volatile bool received;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin(9);
  Wire.onReceive(Event);
}

void Event(char bytes){
  x = Wire.read();
  received = true;
}

void loop() {

  if (received) {
    received = false;
    Serial.print("The character that you entered in the other Arduino is ");
    Serial.println(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Make both volatile?

Comment: yes, it is called from interrupt of course.